# How to add multi-conditional control field in Inspector controls of Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to use Gutenberg inspector controls for developing a slider block with 5 styles. I need to show background color control in style 3 and 4. As their is no conditional attributes to achieve the goal, I've found it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164380/8865972

This solution is only working for one condition, e.g style 3
But I need it working with style 3 and 4.

I've tried bellow code with no luck

```
{ viewStyle==3 || viewStyle==4 && (
    <div>
        {i18n.__( 'Background Color' )}
        <div className="admin_color_palette">
            <ColorIndicator colorValue={ bg_color }/>
            <ColorPalette value={ bg_color } 
            onChange={ ( new_color ) => props.setAttributes( { bg_color: new_color } ) } />
        </div>
    </div> 
)}
```

Comment: I've ended up with the solution:
used  {(viewStyle==3 || viewStyle==4) && instead of {viewStyle==3 || viewStyle==4 &&